# Frame not updating content source

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to switch pages on the button click however it seems to load the "DataCollectionPage.xaml.cs but it doesn't appear on the screen.
The frame's Current source doesn't change.
I only seem to be able to change the frame in the constructor, not the click method.
How can I fix this?

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public  void ButtonAction()
    {

        ContentFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/DataCollectionPage.xaml", 
        UriKind.Relative));
        ContentFrame.NavigationService.Refresh();

    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
   <Frame Source="/CSA;component/Pages/Landing.xaml" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentFrame" 
   Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#2C2F33" Opacity="0.85"  
    />
```

Comment: `Navigate()` is asynchronous.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: @JayBuckman can you elaborate? i don't know how to fix the issue

Comment: In your code, you are starting the `Navigate` process which is asynchronous and then immediately calling `Refresh` which (I suspect) re-navigates to the current content.  The example in the link uses the `LoadCompleted` event to wait the navigation to be complete.  Or you can just use await.